# how to store emojies in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysqli

I tried my best. Still I can't store emojis in the database.
Here is a code which i implemeted.
But the database doesn't support emojis
Please anyone can give me a solution for this?
In databse data stored as    ??????

column alter
`ALTER TABLE  custom_comments CHANGE  "c1"  "c1" TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL ;`

database alter to utf8mb4_unicode_ci

table alter

```
ALTER TABLE  `custom_comments` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

header file `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

sqlquery

```
mysqli_query ($con,"set character_set_client='utf8'");
mysqli_query ($con,"set character_set_results='utf8'");
mysqli_query ($con,"set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
$c1=$_REQUEST['c1'];
$sql_update1 = "INSERT INTO custom_comments (c1) VALUES('".$c1."')";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql_update1)or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

data stored  in database as

```
?ghhhgggggh
??☺
```

connection

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","insta_bot","insta_bot","insta_bot");
$con->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem do you have storing the emojis? Error inserting then in DB? Error in the data you get back from the DB? Other?

Comment: In db data dtored as ???????

Comment: Then edit the question and add the code you use to insert the data in the DB, maybe the problem is in that code.

Comment: Data stored but as ?????? Not a like symbol of emojies

Comment: Yes, I understand that, what I say is that maybe the data is stored as ??????? not because the column collation or connection properties but due to an error on the PHP  code that inserts the data. You should edit the question and put that code.

Comment: I think your problem is because you are creating the connection with utf8 instead of utf8mb4 in the sqlquery section of your code.

Comment: where i change utfmb4 @J.Schmale

Comment: check sql query @AlbertoMartinez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your connection code you are correctly using

> $con->set_charset('utf8mb4');

but then in your sqlquery section you change it to utf8 when it should be utf8mb4:

> mysqli_query ($con,"set character_set_client='utf8mb4'");
>   mysqli_query ($con,"set character_set_results='utf8mb4'");
>   mysqli_query ($con,"set collation_connection='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'");

The [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html) describe how these system variables affect the handling of characters.